# HTTP Location: re-direction -- can browsers addr bar be made to follow the URL?

Tags: python, http, redirect

I use scripting extensively, and use Python to hop around from an executed script back to the page that launched it, or sometimes, other pages entirely.

Say I'm running a script, which we will call "thisplace.cgi", which does its thing, whatever that is, then executes the following:

```
sys.stdout.write('Location: otherplace.cgi\n\n')
raise SystemExit
```

It works -- I get there, the page generated by otherplace.cgi displays properly, functionally speaking, all is good.

HOWEVER. In the browser's location bar, "thisplace.cgi" is still displayed. Not "otherplace.cgi" which is where the user is really at now.

I did some Googling, and from what I gathered (not much... seems curiously mysterious), I ended up sending this...

```
sys.stdout.write('HTTP/1.1 300 Multiple Choices\n')
sys.stdout.write('Location: otherplace.cgi\n\n')
raise SystemExit
```

...but the browser just treats it as invalid and gives me an error page. The CGI environment is some shared-host Debian machine out on the Intertubes. I'm seeing the problem in FireFox under OS X.

Am I  misunderstanding what the 300 is for, or where to use it, or what? Or am I *completely* confused? :)

I just want the browser to show the right thing in the URL bar. Doesn't seem like it's a lot to ask for. No?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect a browser to a different URL you will want to use a `301 Moved Permanently`.  This will cause the browser to fetch the second page and show the new URL.

E.g.

```
sys.stdout.write('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently\n')
sys.stdout.write('Location: otherplace.cgi\n\n')
raise SystemExit
```

Comment: Is that right? Doesn't a 301 also cause caches to miss the intermediate page? Also, I have had no success sending a header at all. One \n, two \n\n, either way, the browser pops up an error page. The only thing that seems to work is Location: wherever\n\n -- Thank you for your post.

Comment: If you want the intermediate page to show something in the browser you probably want to use a Client Side redirect (e.g. JavaScript).  However if you just want your page to execute something and then send the user to another page, just make sure the Redirect is the last thing to execute and it will work fine.  I'm not sure why you are having to put in \n in the first place.  Can you explain why you think they are necessary?  What language are you using, python?  Then you should use urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler.http_error_301

Comment: I am using Python. I do not need any libraries WRT web page production. Strictly STDOUT driven direct emission via sys.stdout.write() When sending a header like Location:, the HTTP spec wants two C/Rs. Most servers under linux translate \n into \r for this purpose. I don't want the intermediate page to show (well, I don't care, really) but I want the final to show, and it isn't -- it stays on the intermediate page. What I do not want is the browser to ignore the intermediate due to 301 notice. Also, I can't get the 1st header to send, which strikes me as just odd.

Comment: Then 301 is correct one to use, this is fairly standard use of it.  By the time the browser gets the 301 response it has already requested the intermediate page, otherwise you wouldn't be sending a response, and it would have processed at the server.  I will add a Python tag to your question and someone with knowledge of Python will then be able to help.

Comment: It's not the first process I'm worried about. It's the *next* one, where the browser has been informed the page was moved -- will it still go there at all after that? Thanks for adding the Python tag, didn't even think of it. Derp. :)

Comment: Yes the browser, will quite happily re-request a page that it has received a 301 response for as browsers don't actually "remember" that.

Comment: ok, thank you. Though I wonder what the point of it is, if it's not remembered. And then there are other levels... the server, proxies, etc. But ok, I'll sure give it a shot, as soon as I can figure out how to emit that header, assuming I can. If I get it working as you describe, I'll come back here and upvote you. :)